# Python3: NewType across files

Tags: python-3.x

I am not a python expert, but I use it.

I want to start making my code more semantic. 
So suppose I have a function

```
def xml_to_csv(xml, csv):
    ...
```

I would like to do something like:

```
def xml_to_csv(xml:FileName, csv:FileName) -> None:
    ...
```

which I can have pass a static type checker by:

```
from typing import NewType
FileName = NewType('FileName', str)
```

So my question is:

1. does it make sense to do this?
2. if it does make sense, how can I have the types I define go across multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure there is no sense, because your `FileName` probably always a string type, but if you want to add annotations you can use something like this.

```
def xml_to_csv(xml: ('FileName', str), csv: 'FileName') -> None:
    ...

print(xml_to_csv.__annotations__)
```

Output:

```
{'xml': ('FileName', <class 'str'>), 'csv': 'FileName', 'return': None}
```